# Improving Virtualbox Performance

Tags: virtualbox

I have a virtualbox6.1 VDI and I want to improve its performance on Ubuntu 20.04 running on a HDD / SSD hybrid machine.  With the /home partition being on the HDD.

My question is..

Can I safely improve the performance of the VDI by placing it onto the SSD root partition? (Are there security issues or other problems that I need to consider?)

Comment: The term “security” in the question is unclear. What do you need to secure the virtual disk from? Aside from this, moving the image to the SSD and updating the setting in VirtualBox to say it’s an SSD will give you a noticeable performance gain.

Comment: Perhaps, I am worrying too much.  With regards to "security" I always worry about accidentally granting root access to things that shouldn't have it.  As habit, I usually never place anything other than ubuntu in the root file system. If you don't see any issues with my proposal I will execute the move, tired of 1 hour boots.

Comment: In your VM settings, set CPU=2 and MEM=2048. That should improve performance.

Comment: @heynnema thx for the feedback, but I like to keep my vm as close to my prod server as possible.  I am  already at CPU=2 and MEM=4096  (I maxed out my machine with additional ram) It just to be ssd vs hdd that is slowing me down.